Tabulator selecting cell
I'm using a Tabulator in spring-boot and want to select a cell on my page, in documentation i found only a range select, but i need to select just one cell (formatter: "textarea:).
When set selectable rows to false then clicking on cell it doesn't highlight.
Here is implementation:
var table = new Tabulator("#main_table", {
             groupHeader: function(value, count, data, group){
                    return value + "<span style='color:black; margin-left:10px;'>(" + count + ")</span>";
                },
                groupHeaderPrint: function(value, count, data, group){
                    return value + "<span style='color:black; margin-left:10px;'></span>";
                },
            //selectableRange:1,
            resizableRows:true,
            footerElement:"<button>Добавить мероприятие</button>",
            autoResize:true,
            placeholder:"Нет данных",
            layout:"fitColumns",
            selectableRows:false,
            //selectableCells:true,
            //selectableRowsRangeMode:"click",
            groupBy:"dateweek",
            columns: table_columns
            //selectableRange: true
        });

Thank you.

I'v solved it like this, add a custom editor:
var cellEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel){
            var cellValue = cell.getValue();
            textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
            
            textArea.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
        
            textArea.style.resize = "none";
            textArea.style.color = "#00008B";
            textArea.style.width = "100%";
            textArea.style.height = "100%";
            textArea.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
            textArea.style.overflow = "hidden";
        
            textArea.value = cellValue;
            
            return input;
        };

